# how to fixCannot autowire argument $em of "..)": it references interface "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager"

Tags: symfony

When I submit my form i got this error:

Cannot autowire argument $em of "App\Controller\LivreController::add1()": it references interface "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please update your post!  Copy and paste your code, instead of screenshotting it.

Comment: Typehint against: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface unless you are doing something unusual.  And yes, get rid of the images.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cerad said, you should use `EntityManagerInterface` instead. Like this.

LivreController.php

```
...

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

...

public function add1(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request) {

    ...

}
```

By the way, verify that you've enabled the autowiring in your `services.yaml`

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
```

[Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)